# Hidden checkboxes for each row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this web application, I fetch the requests from a database and display the data in a table in a jsp page. I would like to add a function which displays a checkbox next to each row such that the checkbox appears only when mouse hovers over that row. Selecting that checkbox would enable me to draw the data from the row so as to insert the new data back into the database. Any help regarding this would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.
This is my current code.

```
<table class="actable" >
 <tr>
  <td>RequestID</td>
  <td>Requester</td>
  <td>Approver</td>
  <td>Status</td>
  <td>Product</td>
  <td>Version</td>
  <td>Source</td>
  <td>Destination</td>
 </tr>
 <%
 for(int i=0;i<reqjsp.size();i++) //reqjsp being the ArrayList that I forward to this jsp from my servlet
 {
 %>
 <tr>  
  <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getRequestid() %></td>               
  <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getRequestor() %></td>  
  <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getApprover() %></td>  
  <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getStatus() %></td>  
  <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getProduct() %></td>
  <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getVersion() %></td>
  <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getSource() %></td>  
  <td><%= reqjsp.get(i).getDestination() %></td>  
 </tr> 
 <%} %>          
  </table>
```

Comment: add a hidden checkbox unchecked, then on hover display it, if it doesn't get checked hide it on mouse out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with CSS:

```
.actable tr input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

.actable tr:hover input[type=checkbox] {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/owUdAF/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/owUdAF/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is the checkboxes have to be outside the rows. This inserts them into the table itself. Or is there any way to hide a column altogether?

Comment: @AnkurChachra: If the checkboxes are in the table, they have to be in a table cell (`td`), as it's invalid for them to be anywhere else. The only valid place for a `td` is a `tr`. Yes, you can hide an entire column, but if you then show the column on individual rows, the display will be unpleasant. Simply put the checkboxes in an existing cell, perhaps floated right or similar.